# How to update colors within a DrawingImage

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, themes

Our application has been converted to use vector images using the DrawingImage paradigm. I would like to make the colors/brushes within the DrawingImage variable and have no luck working it out.

WHY:
My reasoning for doing this is that we are using themes within our application and I would like to change all of the images when a theme changes. Technically, I just want to change the colors not the image.

WHAT I'VE TRIED:
I have declared the colors (I say colors because there are different types of pens/brushes used within the image) as a DynamicResource hooking up to a defined brush and then tried to update that brush via binding and I don't get a change. I have also tried to redraw the image by binding it and then redrawing it when the ApplicationThemeChanged event fires. This still doesn't work which surprises me.

A SIDE NOTE:
I am mainly wanting to do this in buttons and have extended the Button class for added functionality calling it a VectorButton. My point is that I have the VectorButton.cs file an available means to make changes.

If you need code samples of anything specific, just ask and I'll post. I think it's pretty self-explanatory though.

Thanks for help in advance!

DrawingImage Example (I am swapping out ResourceDictionaries when the theme changes. Each resource dictionary has it's how copy of PrimaryColor, but with a different color value.)

```
    <DrawingImage x:Key="myVectorIconDrawingImage">
        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,744.09448,1052.3622" />
                </DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
                <DrawingGroup>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            <Pen Brush="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}" Thickness="1" StartLineCap="Flat" EndLineCap="Flat" LineJoin="Miter" />
                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <PathGeometry FillRule="EvenOdd" Figures="M239.0625,299L239.0625,349 289.0625,349 289.0625,299 239.0625,299z M309.5625,299.5L309.5625,348.53125 507.59375,348.53125 507.59375,299.5 309.5625,299.5z M239.0625,384L239.0625,434 289.0625,434 289.0625,384 239.0625,384z M309.5625,384.5L309.5625,433.53125 507.59375,433.53125 507.59375,384.5 309.5625,384.5z M239.0625,469L239.0625,519 289.0625,519 289.0625,469 239.0625,469z M309.5625,469.5L309.5625,518.53125 507.59375,518.53125 507.59375,469.5 309.5625,469.5z" />
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
    </DrawingImage>
```

Comment: Yes please, provide some code sample. It would be useful for future visitors.

Comment: I'm not sure what code you would like to see... I will post a snippet of a DrawingImage I guess? If you have any suggestions, please post.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you look into [pixel shaders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.shadereffect(v=vs.110).aspx).